# Reopen recovered docs pane in MS Word 2003?

Tags: data-recovery, microsoft-word-2003

I hit the <kbd>close</kbd> button after choosing which doc to work with, now I can't remember how to get the window to reopen.

This is the pane that shows if your document got corrupted/word crashed and it usually offers the original and 'recovered' version

Comment: Can't you just go into the autorecovery directory and copy the backup files? Also look your document's directory. Work makes a temporary copy of your working document in the document's folder.

Comment: The autosave option was not checked (thanks corporate default!) where is the autorecovery directory?

Comment: By default, it is under %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word. For you, %APPDATA% will probably be the Roaming folder.

Comment: For more on this, see http://www.gmayor.com/automatically_backup.htm.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827099) is the Microsoft article detailing searching for corrupter / lost Word files. Hopefully this helps to start with.

[This](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_7175455_open-autorecover-word-document.html) site details how you could go about finding such documents .

> There are a few different methods to recover your data.
>
> Instructions
>   **Automatic Document Recovery**
>
> Open the Windows Task Manager by pressing "Control," "Alt" and
>   "Delete" at the same time.
>
> Under the "Processes" tab, ensure that no instance of Word is running,
>   and choose "End Process" for anything that might be Word.
>
> Reopen Word. The "Document Recovery" task pane should open on the left
>   hand side of the window with your document listed in it. Click on your
>   document, then "Save As" to save it.
>
> **Search in Word**
>
> Click "Recent" in the "File" menu in Word 2010, then click "Recover
>   Unsaved Documents" and search for your AutoRecover file, which will
>   end in ".asd."
>
> Click on "Word Options" in the Microsoft Office Word button in Word
>   2007. Click "Save" in the following navigation pane and note the
>   folder path in the "AutoRecover File Location" box. Click "Cancel,"
>   close Word and open and navigate through a "My Computer" window to
>   find the folder path you noted before. It should contain your .asd
>   file.
>
> Click "Options" under the "Tools" menu in Word 2002 or 2003. Under the
>   "File Locations" tab, double click on "AutoRecover files" and note the
>   folder path, then close out the "Options" window and close Word. Open
>   a "My Computer" window and find the folder noted earlier. It should
>   contain your .asd file.
>
> **Search in Windows**
>
> Click on the "Start" menu in the lower left corner of your desktop.
>   Type ".asd" in the "Start Search" box (Vista or Windows 7) or "*.asd"
>   in the box under "Search for files or folders named" (XP). If using
>   XP, you'll additionally have to choose "My Computer" from the "Look
>   in" box. Hit "Enter" or click "Search Now" to search for the file.
>
> Start Word and click "Open" from the "File" menu in Word 2010. In this
>   list of "Files of type," click on "All files." Navigate to the .asd
>   file you found and click "Open."
>
> Start Word and click "Open" from inside the Microsoft Office button in
>   Word 2007. In this list of "Files of type," click on "All files."
>   Navigate to the .asd file you found and click "Open."
>
> Start Word and click on "Open" from the "File" menu in Word 2002 or
>   2003. In the list of "Files of type," click on "All Files *.*"
>   Navigate to the .asd file you found and open it. Restart your computer
>   using the Windows "Shut Down" menu and start Word. The "Document
>   Recovery" task pane should open on the left side of the window with
>   your document in it

Comment: I already looked at that and it doesn't seem to tell you how to pop that pane/window back open

Comment: Seems the only way is to exit Word completely and then re-enter. From what I can find it opens on startup if there are files present in the auto-recovery folder.

Comment: I just fired up word and this window does not appear, this despite me selecting the 'want to keep working with these files' option (slightly paraphrased) previously

Comment: Even worse, I just tried this method http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/use-the-document-recovery-task-pane-to-recover-files-HP003078411.aspx which totally crashed word, causing some kind of restart which is no longer listing the files I originally was working with. A POX ON YOU MR GATES!!!! etc....